# Apache2 is not starting in Pop OS

Tags: apache-httpd, pop-os, xampp

I'm trying to install xampp, and even though the MySQL is working, I can't get Apache started. I have tried many solutions. Below is the output I get when I run `sudo systemctl status apache2`

[image]

I have little experience with Linux and I would appreciate any help. If you want any more information, please mention and I will update the post accordingly. TIA!

Answer (score 1):

The `AH00072` messages tell us that another program has already allocated port 80, possibly a previous attempt to start a web server.

You can find which process with `sudo lsof -itcp:80`.